# Tensorflow Data API: prefetch when training on CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator, data-pipeline

I'm training on a MacBook pro (no GPU). After watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxOsJPaxHME I saw that I could improve my input pipeline by reordering some ops and adding `num_parallel_calls`.

#### Question:

Since I'm not using a GPU, does it make sense to include `dataset.prefetch(1)` to the end of my pipeline?

Comment: Probably not. Have you measured any difference on your Mac book?

Comment: Have not benchmarked hoping someone had already done that work. Guess I know what I'll be doing today...